# Display data in the column as a row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to get the column names of the table in a CSV manner.

```
select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'USER_TABLE';
```

`USER_TABLE` having five columns as below

```
Column_name
-------------
A
B
C
D
E
```

But I need the output as,

```
A, B, C, D, E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LISTAGG is the thing from oracle to to that:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY  column_id) csv
FROM all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'USER_TABLE';
```

Comment: what is there are too many columns?? i am hitting with ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) to generate a CSV list of the column names in your table:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) "Column Names"
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'USER_TABLE'
```